# I encountered "Platform Android Configuration Error"

Tags: vuforia

The first startup is normal, but after exiting the application, there will be an error of "PLATFORM ANDROID CONFIGINALIZATION ERROR", as shown in the image below. After clearing all data, it can be successfully run again
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iEkv.jpg)

I don't know what to do next, I have already added the key

This is the error log

```
2024-01-17 17:38:48.030  3109-3129  Unity                   com.vuforia.engine.coresamples       E  Vuforia initialization failed: PLATFORM_ANDROID_CONFIG_INITIALIZATION_ERROR
                                                                                                
                                                                                                PLATFORM ANDROID CONFIG INITIALIZATION ERROR
                                                                                                
                                                                                                Failed to initialize Vuforia Engine.
                                                                                                UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
                                                                                                InitErrorHandler:ShowErrorMessage(VuforiaInitError)
                                                                                                System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
                                                                                                System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
                                                                                                Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
                                                                                                Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling(Action`1, T)
```

Comment: is Google Play Services for AR up-to-date on the device? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core&hl=en&gl=US

Comment: Yes, I just updated to the latest version

Comment: Is this problem specific to a device or device model? Is this device on the list of recommended devices here? https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/recommended-devices